# Moment Generating Function

Tags: beta-distribution, moment-generating-function

Suppose X is a random variable with a Beta  distribution and 
x in (0,1)

How can I prove moment generating function exist

Comment: Beta mgf : https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Moment_Generating_Function_of_Beta_Distribution

Comment: The sum manifestly has infinitely many non-zero terms.  It also obviously converges everywhere because, term by term, the absolute values are only $1/(2k+1)$ as great as the terms in the series for $e^t,$ which converges everywhere.  Could you therefore explain what you mean by the sum being "finite"?

Comment: https://www.statlect.com/probability-distributions/beta-distribution in this example if you click on "proof" in the moment generating function of beta (general case) proof it says that moment generating function exists because , the integral  is guaranteed to exist and be finite. In a similar way am trying to check if the integral exists for a= 1/2 and b =1 => the mgf exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, since the Beta distributions have support on $[0,1]$, the mgf exists; that is, it is finite (for all parameters $(a,b)$). $\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}} M_X(t)=\E e^{t X} =\int_0^1 e^{tx} f_{\text{Beta}}(x)\; dx$.  But for $x \in [0,1]$ we have $e^{-|t|}\le e^{tx}\le e^{|t|},$ so always $e^{-|t|}\le M_X(t)\le e^{|t|}$. So if your sum is a correct representation of the mgf it would have to converge ...

The looking at your sum
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^k}{k! (2k+1)}
$$ the factor $(2k+1) \ge 1;$ and dropping it from the sum, we get the sum for $e^t$, so that will be an upper bound. So convergence is clear.

Comment: $ M_X(t) $ = $\mathbb{E}[e^{tX}]$ =$  \frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2} +1)}{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2} ) +\Gamma(1)}  \int_0^1 e^{tX} x^{\frac{1}{2}-1} (1-x)^{1-1}\ dx   $= ${\frac{1}{2}}$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty$ $\int_0^1 \frac{{t^kx}^k}{k!}$ $x^{-\frac{1}{2}} \ dx$ =    
$\frac{1}{2}$ $ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^k}{k!}$ $\int_0^1 {}$ $x^{k-\frac{1}{2}} \ dx$ = $ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^k}{k! (2k+1)}$ 
  Do you think there is something wrong with my calculation?

Comment: No, because your calculation is identical to the general formula shown on Wikipedia for the mgf of the Beta Distribution.